# Handle table that has relationship one-to-many and many-to-many in relational database

Tags: sql, database-design

I am having interesting problem with database design but i am not able to figure it out.

I have 2 tables:

```
customers
    id              unsigned int(P)
    name            varchar(30)
    ...

+----+---------+-----+
| id | name    | ... |
+----+---------+-----+
|  1 | Jame    | ... |
|  2 | Tom     | ... |
| .. | ....... | ... |
+----+---------+-----+


appointments
    id              unsigned int(P)
    customer_id     fk(customers.id)
    ...

+----+------------+-----+
| id | customer_id| ... |
+----+------------+-----+
|  1 | 1.         | ... |
|  2 | 2          | ... |
| .. | .......... | ... |
+----+---------+-----+
```

So the relationship between `customers` and `appointments` is one-to-many (one appointment can only have one customer)

However, later on i need to have another table as below:

```
tickets
        id              unsigned int(P)
        customer_id     fk(customers.id)
        appointment_id. fk(appointments.id)
        ...
    
    +----+------------+----------------+
    | id | customer_id| appointment_id |
    +----+------------+----------------+
    |  1 | 1.         | 1              |
    |  2 | 2          | 2              |
    | .. | .......... | .............. |
    +----+------------+----------------+
```

This `tickets` table is to keep track if the customer coming to the appointment or not. If the customer coming without appointment. Thats ok. the `appointment_id` will be set `null` but `customer_id` still need to be assigned to get customer information from `customers` table.
However this table make the relation of `customers` and `appointments` become many-to-many.

Two tables cant have to relationships at the sametime. Something not correct here and i dont know where.

My question is about the `tickets` table is to keep track who is coming to the appointment. I currently cannot insert into `tickets` table cause its complaining about multiple relationship between `customers` and `appointments`. How can i redesign the `tickets` table ? i want this table to hold the customer and appointments information for both walking( appointment_id == null) or appointment (appointment_id == int) customer.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you also include the code you are using to insert rows into the `tickets` table, whether it be SQL or some ORM library usage?

Comment: See [Associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

Comment: Hi daniel8x. You make an appointment for a customer if he/she is walk-in customer then there is no appointment thus there is no track till he/she gives you an id to make one, right?

Answer (score 1):

In the design you show, a customer can have zero or more appointments (the relationship between appointment::customer is zero-to-many, not one-to-one).

And it looks like you want each appointment to have zero or more tickets.

That means, if you know the appointment id, you can find the customer id. So your tickets table does not need a customer_id column, just an appointment_id column.

You're quite right that the customer_id column in **tickets** is confusing, because it's not needed.

If you know a ticket ID and you want the customer and appointment information, you use JOIN operations to follow the chain backward. Like this:

```sql
SELECT tickets.*, appointments.*, customers.*
  FROM tickets
  JOIN appointments ON tickets.appointment_id = appointments.id
  JOIN customers ON appointments.customer_id = customers.id
 WHERE tickets.id = <<<some ticket you want to look up>>>
```

Relational databases are *designed for this purpose*. Thousands of programmer years of labor have built systems that do this work efficiently.

There's a complex mathematical system called "normalization" around this. Put simply it says: "never store information in more than one place." You're proposed tickets table does that by storing the customer_id next to the appointment_id. That customer_id value can always be found in the appointments table, so don't duplicate it.

> *Somemthing not correct here ...*

You have a good instinct. Trust it. Learn about normalization.

Comment: Thanks. i think i got it. The only thing i am still not getting it. is that. If the customer is a walkin customer ( no appointment). Then how can get customer information in tickets table. because for this type of customer, appointment_id will be `null` (no appointment)